# Firebase Crashlytics Minify R8 Android

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, crashlytics, android-r8

The app works fine under normal instances but when I try to implement minify and R8. This raises the following error.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:uploadCrashlyticsMappingFileAlpha'.
> Failed to calculate the value of task ':app:uploadCrashlyticsMappingFileAlpha' property 'googleServicesResourceRoot'.
   > Could not get unknown property 'intermediateDir' for task ':app:processAlphaGoogleServices' of type com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesTask.
```

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:uploadCrashlyticsMappingFileAlpha'.

//..... More Error Line
```

I get the above error and
Absolutely have no idea what's happening.

```
buildTypes {
        getByName("debug") {
            applicationIdSuffix = ".sandbox"
            debuggable true
        }
        alpha {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            versionNameSuffix ".alpha"
        }
}
```

This is the above code I used and I am trying to build Alpha but when I Debug works fine.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

### **Update**

There is a new version for Google Play Services, and it seems to fix the issue. You can use `4.3.13`. They have brought back the missing function for this sake.

---

**Original Answer**

Please downgrade the Google Play Services to `4.3.10`. I don't know the reasoning behind it, but it seems `4.3.12` is not compatible.

Here is the issue I created on Google issuetracker:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/237071883